# Authenticate window doesn’t appear anymore

Tags: lubuntu

Authenticate window doesn’t appear anymore in my Lubuntu 11.10 64bit
When I try to run Synaptic or Time and Date from menu, nothing goes on. I can authenticate and run the programs only in console.

```
** (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:1319): WARNING **: Unable to register authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Cannot determine user of subject
Cannot register authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Cannot determine user of subject
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and it was a race situation.  lxpolkit was trying apparently to start too early in the boot and failing for some reason, causing the above error. Try finding the command on the "Exec=" line in the desktop file in autostart.  Try running that at the command-line after your desktop has started and then, with that terminal open, try authenticating whatever you were having trouble with.  If it works, then you know that you just need to delay the process, which is done easily in a startup bash script such as:
    #!/bin/bash
    sleep 5s
    while [ 1 ] ; do /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/lxpolkit ; sleep 2s ; done&
    exit
and then make it executable and create a desktop file pointing to that script in ~/autostart